# RestSharp Post Request with serialized JSON object

Tags: c#, rest, api, restsharp

I am trying to post a serialized object using RestSharp object is :

```
public class WebCRMOrganisation : IWebCRMOrganisation
{
    [JsonProperty("OrganisationAddress")]
    public string OrganisationAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationAlert")]
    public string OrganisationAlert { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationApprovalStatus")]
    public long OrganisationApprovalStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCity")]
    public string OrganisationCity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationComment")]
    public string OrganisationComment { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCompareName")]
    public string OrganisationCompareName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCountry")]
    public string OrganisationCountry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCreatedAt")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset OrganisationCreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCreatedBy")]
    public string OrganisationCreatedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationDivisionName")]
    public string OrganisationDivisionName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationDomain")]
    public string OrganisationDomain { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationExtraCustom1")]
    public string OrganisationExtraCustom1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationExtraCustom2")]
    public string OrganisationExtraCustom2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationExtraCustom3")]
    public string OrganisationExtraCustom3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationExtraCustom4")]
    public string OrganisationExtraCustom4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationExtraCustom5")]
    public string OrganisationExtraCustom5 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationExtraCustom6")]
    public string OrganisationExtraCustom6 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationExtraCustom7")]
    public string OrganisationExtraCustom7 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationExtraCustom8")]
    public string OrganisationExtraCustom8 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationFax")]
    public string OrganisationFax { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationGps")]
    public string OrganisationGps { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationId")]
    public long OrganisationId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationImageFileExtension")]
    public string OrganisationImageFileExtension { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationIndustry")]
    public string OrganisationIndustry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationLastDisplayedAt")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset OrganisationLastDisplayedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationLastItemType")]
    public string OrganisationLastItemType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationLastItemUpdatedAt")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset OrganisationLastItemUpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationMarketDataId")]
    public string OrganisationMarketDataId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationName")]
    public string OrganisationName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationNoAds")]
    public bool OrganisationNoAds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationHistory")]
    public string OrganisationHistory { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationOutlookSync")]
    public long OrganisationOutlookSync { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationOverlayUrl")]
    public string OrganisationOverlayUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationOwner")]
    public long OrganisationOwner { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationOwner2")]
    public long OrganisationOwner2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPostCode")]
    public string OrganisationPostCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationReportTemp")]
    public long OrganisationReportTemp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationSla")]
    public long OrganisationSla { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationState")]
    public string OrganisationState { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationStatus")]
    public string OrganisationStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationTelephone")]
    public string OrganisationTelephone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationTelephoneSearch")]
    public string OrganisationTelephoneSearch { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationTerritoryId")]
    public long OrganisationTerritoryId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationType")]
    public string OrganisationType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationUpdatedAt")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset OrganisationUpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationUpdatedBy")]
    public string OrganisationUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationVatCountry")]
    public string OrganisationVatCountry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationVatGroup")]
    public string OrganisationVatGroup { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationVatNumber")]
    public string OrganisationVatNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationVatStatus")]
    public string OrganisationVatStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationVatVerifiedAt")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset OrganisationVatVerifiedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationWww")]
    public string OrganisationWww { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXDate1")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset OrganisationXDate1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXDate2")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset OrganisationXDate2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXInt1")]
    public long OrganisationXInt1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXInt2")]
    public long OrganisationXInt2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXInt3")]
    public long OrganisationXInt3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXInt4")]
    public long OrganisationXInt4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXInt5")]
    public long OrganisationXInt5 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXInt6")]
    public long OrganisationXInt6 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXInt7")]
    public long OrganisationXInt7 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXInt8")]
    public long OrganisationXInt8 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXMemo1")]
    public string OrganisationXMemo1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXMemo2")]
    public string OrganisationXMemo2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXText1")]
    public string OrganisationXText1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXText2")]
    public string OrganisationXText2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXText3")]
    public string OrganisationXText3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXText4")]
    public string OrganisationXText4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXText5")]
    public string OrganisationXText5 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXText6")]
    public string OrganisationXText6 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXText7")]
    public string OrganisationXText7 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationXText8")]
    public string OrganisationXText8 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus1")]
    public string OrganisationPlus1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus2")]
    public string OrganisationPlus2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus3")]
    public string OrganisationPlus3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus4")]
    public string OrganisationPlus4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus5")]
    public string OrganisationPlus5 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus6")]
    public string OrganisationPlus6 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus7")]
    public string OrganisationPlus7 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus8")]
    public string OrganisationPlus8 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus9")]
    public string OrganisationPlus9 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus10")]
    public string OrganisationPlus10 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus11")]
    public string OrganisationPlus11 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus12")]
    public string OrganisationPlus12 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus13")]
    public string OrganisationPlus13 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus14")]
    public string OrganisationPlus14 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus15")]
    public string OrganisationPlus15 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus16")]
    public string OrganisationPlus16 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus17")]
    public string OrganisationPlus17 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus18")]
    public string OrganisationPlus18 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus19")]
    public string OrganisationPlus19 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationPlus20")]
    public string OrganisationPlus20 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom1")]
    public string OrganisationCustom1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom2")]
    public string OrganisationCustom2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom3")]
    public string OrganisationCustom3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom4")]
    public string OrganisationCustom4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom5")]
    public string OrganisationCustom5 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom6")]
    public string OrganisationCustom6 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom7")]
    public string OrganisationCustom7 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom8")]
    public string OrganisationCustom8 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom9")]
    public string OrganisationCustom9 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom10")]
    public string OrganisationCustom10 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom11")]
    public string OrganisationCustom11 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom12")]
    public string OrganisationCustom12 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom13")]
    public string OrganisationCustom13 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom14")]
    public string OrganisationCustom14 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationCustom15")]
    public string OrganisationCustom15 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrganisationMemo")]
    public string OrganisationMemo { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried the following code but every time I am getting bad request in response, I have checked API reference documentation JSON format is correct and I have also tried API's swagger reference I am able to  use their methods fine.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.webcrm.com");

var request = new RestRequest("Organisations", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(organisation), 
     ParameterType.RequestBody);

WebCRMConnectivityResult c = CheckConnectivity();
request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}",c.AccessToken));
//request.RootElement = "organisation";
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

var content = response.Content;
```

Can anyone please tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: have you checked that date-times are formatted in the correct format?

Comment: Can you make it work through Postman? Postman has a code generation feature for RestSharp.

Comment: I have tried it using Postman it gives a TargetInvocationException

Comment: Field "OrganisationCustom1" gave me errors! It's a vat field and I think it has some special value and/or type check. Just don't use it at all.
If you still have issues then get back!